# How to implement or use fabric.Textbox and fabric.iText classes in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, npm, fabricjs

[Fabric.js Textbox and IText](http://fabricjs.com/super-sub-script)

I am trying to implement auto-expand and auto-resize the textbox feature as shown in the above link in Reactjs.

I tried using react-input-autosize and fabric packages in the npm. Textbox and IText classes are not present in fabric packages and react-input-autosize package do not allow auto-resize property of textbox.

Can anybody advise me how to approach this ? I am unable to find any existing package that could help me achieve this.

Thank you in advance.